# Auto Populate SMS is not working for languages other than English using SMS Retriever API

Tags: android, api, sms, populate, auto

Google Play restricts the use of high risk or sensitive permissions, including the SMS or Call Log permission groups. Now we are using SMS Retriever API for auto populating the OTP.

Auto populate SMS is working only for English. For other regional languages SMS is not auto populating.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I tried SMS Retriever API for Turkish, it worked for us perfectly. But because of the regulations in Turkey, we have to add a code like B002 at the end of SMS message, so we cannot use this api now. I think that this api should be improved in some ways to meet our needs.